# Drop a Prometheus label / tag

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I've got metrics that looks like this

```
kafka_lag{client_id="dcp-0",partition="53"} 1977005
kafka_lag{client_id="dcp-10",partition="53"} 2345234
```

When I visualize in grafana I get two different lines, however I would like to drop `client_id` and display only `kafka_lag{partition="53"}` values.

How can I drop a tag from Prometheus output?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two values at the same time (in your case, the lag for different client) and you want to view only one, you need to combine them in a way that make sense.

By example:

- `max(kafka_lag) by(partition)` if you want to view the maximum lag
- `avg(kafka_lag) by(partition)` if you want to have a sense of overall lag

Any of the [aggregation operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) can be used to extract information.